# How do I find dual Screen iPad apps

Tags: ipad, appletv, airplay, dual-screen

A feature of having an [Apple TV is Dual Screen](http://www.apple.com/uk/appletv/airplay/) with an iPad. I would like to find games and apps that use this feature. How would I specify this within the app store? or is there a list online somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [AppleNApps](http://applenapps.com/feature/the-best-apps-for-airplay-mirroring-on-ipad-2-and-iphone-4s)

This is a list of games which take full advantage of AirPlay Mirroring by offering **special full screen 720P HD modes** to show off the power of the A5 ship.

There are other apps that work with AirPlay Mirroring which are not in this list, but they’re either poor apps overall, or it’s not a smooth translation.

(last updated on 7th November 2011)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of resources:

- [Apple's Featured AirPlay List (iTunes link)](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewRoom?affC=QQABAAAAHgAJb9EiLjdXYWFUTjZ1bWMtcnJkbzg3UVBHaFJmT3hQdFpUV0Zhdw==&cc=us&fcId=425698687&id=25204&ign-mscache=1&ign-msr=http://www.9to5mac.com/56088/apple-lists-airplay-enabled-apps-in-a-new-app-store-section/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%2b9To5Mac-MacAllDay%2b%289%2bto%2b5%2bMac%2b-%2bApple%2bIntelligence%29&mt=8)
- [TheApple.tv's curated list](http://theapple.tv/apps/list-of-airplay-enabled-apps/)